# Update based on group by, top 1 row and where case

Tags: sql, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follows: 
[image: table select]

This is a result of this select:

```
SELECT ParentID, ID, [Default], IsOnTop, OrderBy
  FROM [table]
  WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT ParentID
      FROM [table]
      GROUP BY ParentID
      HAVING SUM([Default]) <> 1)
  ORDER BY ParentID
```

Now, what I want to do is to: for each `ParentID` group, set one of the rows as a Default (`[Default] = 1`), where the row is chosen using this logic: 
 if group has a row with `IsOnTop = 1` then take this row, otherwise take top 1 row ordered by `OrderBy`. 
I'm completly clueless as on how to do that in SQL and I have over 40 of such groups, thus I'd like to ask you for help, preferably with some explanation of your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just slightly modify your current query by assigning a row number, across each `ParentID` group.  The ordering logic for the row number assignment is that records with `IsOnTop` values of 1 come first, and after that the `OrderBy` column determines position.  I update the CTE under the condition that only the first record in each `ParentID` group gets assigned a `Default` value of 1.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ParentID, ID, [Default], IsOnTop, OrderBy,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID
                           ORDER BY IsOnTop DESC, OrderBy) rn
    FROM [table]
    WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT ParentID FROM [table]
                       GROUP BY ParentID HAVING SUM([Default]) <> 1)
)

UPDATE cte
SET [Default] = 1
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Are you sure `row_number` can contain 2 `order by`? I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.` (line 4) and `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` (line 7)

Comment: @user6807975 Typo: I had a comma after `PARTITION BY` ... remove it and the query should work (see the updated answer).

Comment: The line containing `)` is also not needed. But I'm getting mixed results with this query, sometimes even though there are no `IsOnTop = 1`, Default gets assigned to a row which has `OrderBy = 2`

Comment: For that group which got assigned a default of `OrderBy = 2`, what should have been the correct assignment?  I can't easily test my code.  Do you want the smallest `OrderBy` value to get the assignment when `IsOnTop` is never 1, or do you want the largest `OrderBy` value?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, it seems these records had already set `Default` before the query, so it seems it works just fine, thank you

Comment: @user6807975 If you need a way to avoid groups which already have an assignment, I can update my answer.  Let me know what you need.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a quicker way but this is how I would do it.
First create a CTE

First we create a CTE in which we add a row_number over the ParentID's based on if IsOnTop = 1. Else it picks the 1st row based on the OrderBy column.

Then we update the rows with the rownumber 1.

```
WITH FindSoonToBeDefault AS (
     SELECT ParentID, ID, [Default], IsOnTop, OrderBy, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY IsOnTop DESC, [OrderBy] ASC) AS [rn]
     FROM [table]
 WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT ParentID
     FROM [table]
     GROUP BY ParentID
     HAVING SUM([Default]) <> 1)
 ORDER BY ParentID
)
UPDATE FindSoonToBeDefault
SET [Default] = 1
WHERE [rn] = 1
```

In your screenshot row 12 will be default.
Row 13 will be not.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY IsOnTop DESC, [OrderBy]`

Comment: My bad, 0 comes before 1. Edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify `ASC` as ascending is the default order.  Not wrong to use it here for clarity, just not needed. +1

Answer (score 0):

`(1-IsOnTop)*OrderBy` combines `IsOnTop` and `OrderBy` into a single result that can be ranked so that the lowest value is the one you want. Use a derived table to identify the lowest result for each `ParentID`, then`JOIN` to that to identify your defaults.

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [Default] = 1
FROM [table]
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ParentID, MIN((1-IsOnTop)*OrderBy) DefaultRank
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY ParentID
) AS rankForDefault
ON rankForDefault.ParentID=[table].ParentID
AND rankForDefault.DefaultRank=(1-[table].IsOnTop)*[table].OrderBy
```

Comment: There are some syntax problems with your query which I'm unable to identify. I thought that inner join should have a `FROM` statement, but that didn't fix it, in both cases the msg is: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.`

Comment: I was missing the FROM clause in the derived table.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I tried fixing that, that still didn't fix the problem. Also, even with the FROM, MS SQL Studio still cannot identify the columns in that  join.

Comment: I've taken some extra parentheses out. Sorry - I wrote my original answer without access to SQL server to test it

Comment: Your query updates both the rows with and without defaults already set, thus setting more than 1 default per group.